# Baffling SQL Parsing Issue: WHERE clause parsing ends before all conditions

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr4

I am doing this in Antlr 4 however I believe this has nothing to do specifically with that.
I am parsing the WHERE clause of an SQL SELECT statement. The parser fails to conjure up individual condition clauses together.
The error is:

```
line 4:44 mismatched input 'AND' expecting {'EXCEPT', 'FROM', GROUP, ...
```

This is the input statement:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3
FROM T1
WHERE   (NS1.Func1(col1, 123) == false) AND 
        (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Func2(col2))) AND
        (NOT (NS2.Func3(col3) == "1")) ;
```

The problematic AND is actually the 2nd one in the where clause. The first one gets parsed properly.
I expected the 2nd AND to also fall under:
expression_body (expression_tail)* rule. However for some reason it does not.

I have pasted the token stream and the tree output below.
Note that on the tree the "where" clause actually has ended before processing the 2nd AND.

Relevant parts of Grammar (if you need more let me know pls):

```
where_clause:
    WHERE expression
    ;

expression:
    expression_body (expression_tail)*
    ;

expression_tail:
    comparison_operator expression
    | comparison_operator (ALL | SOME | ANY) LPAREN select_query RPAREN
    | IN LPAREN expression ( COMMA expression )* RPAREN
    | IS (NOT)? NULL
    | NOT? LIKE expression ( ESCAPE expression )?
    | common_clause_token expression
    ;

expression_body:
    DEFAULT 
    | STAR
    | NULL 
    | func_call
    | BETWEEN expression AND expression
    | IF LPAREN expression COMMA expression COMMA expression RPAREN
    | windowing_func
    | EXISTS LPAREN select_query RPAREN
    | LPAREN expression RPAREN
    | identifier_up_to_two_parts
    | CHAR
    | NUMBER
    | STRING
    ;

func_call:
    UNQUOTEDIDENTIFIER ( DOT ( UNQUOTEDIDENTIFIER | func_call) )* LPAREN ( expression (COMMA expression)*)? RPAREN
    | CAST LPAREN expression AS data_type RPAREN
    | AGG LPAREN (DISTINCT)? expression RPAREN
    ;

common_clause_token:
    NUMBER 
    |   CHAR 
    |   UNQUOTEDIDENTIFIER
    |   PUNCTUATION
    |   KEYWORD
    |   AND
    |   OR 
    |   STAR
    |   DOT 
    |   LT
    |   EQ
    |   GT
    |   Q
    |   LBRKT
    |   RBRKT
    ;
```

Token List:

```
[0,0:5,<SELECT> = 'SELECT']
[1,6:6,<WS> = ' ']
[2,7:10,<UNQUOTEDIDENTIFIER> = 'col1']
[3,11:11,<COMMA> = ',']
[4,12:12,<WS> = ' ']
[5,13:16,<UNQUOTEDIDENTIFIER> = 'col2']
[6,17:17,<COMMA> = ',']
[7,18:18,<WS> = ' ']
[8,19:22,<UNQUOTEDIDENTIFIER> = 'col3']
[9,23:24,<WS> = '
']
[10,25:28,<FROM> = 'FROM']
[11,29:29,<WS> = ' ']
[12,30:31,<UNQUOTEDIDENTIFIER> = 'T1']
[13,32:33,<WS> = '
']
[14,34:38,<WHERE> = 'WHERE']
[15,39:41,<WS> = '   ']
[16,42:42,<LPAREN> = '(']
[17,43:45,<UNQUOTEDIDENTIFIER> = 'NS1']
[18,46:46,<DOT> = '.']
[19,47:51,<UNQUOTEDIDENTIFIER> = 'Func1']
[20,52:52,<LPAREN> = '(']
[21,53:56,<UNQUOTEDIDENTIFIER> = 'col1']
[22,57:57,<COMMA> = ',']
[23,58:58,<WS> = ' ']
[24,59:61,<NUMBER> = '123']
[25,62:62,<RPAREN> = ')']
[26,63:63,<WS> = ' ']
[27,64:65,<PUNCTUATION> = '==']
[28,66:66,<WS> = ' ']
[29,67:71,<UNQUOTEDIDENTIFIER> = 'false']
[30,72:72,<RPAREN> = ')']
[31,73:73,<WS> = ' ']
[32,74:76,<AND> = 'AND']
[33,77:87,<WS> = ' 
        ']
[34,88:88,<LPAREN> = '(']
[35,89:94,<UNQUOTEDIDENTIFIER> = 'String']
[36,95:95,<DOT> = '.']
[37,96:108,<UNQUOTEDIDENTIFIER> = 'IsNullOrEmpty']
[38,109:109,<LPAREN> = '(']
[39,110:114,<UNQUOTEDIDENTIFIER> = 'Func2']
[40,115:115,<LPAREN> = '(']
[41,116:119,<UNQUOTEDIDENTIFIER> = 'col2']
[42,120:120,<RPAREN> = ')']
[43,121:121,<RPAREN> = ')']
[44,122:122,<RPAREN> = ')']
[45,123:123,<WS> = ' ']
[46,124:126,<AND> = 'AND']
[47,127:136,<WS> = '
        ']
[48,137:137,<LPAREN> = '(']
[49,138:140,<NOT> = 'NOT']
[50,141:141,<WS> = ' ']
[51,142:142,<LPAREN> = '(']
[52,143:145,<UNQUOTEDIDENTIFIER> = 'NS2']
[53,146:146,<DOT> = '.']
[54,147:151,<UNQUOTEDIDENTIFIER> = 'Func3']
[55,152:152,<LPAREN> = '(']
[56,153:156,<UNQUOTEDIDENTIFIER> = 'col3']
[57,157:157,<RPAREN> = ')']
[58,158:158,<WS> = ' ']
[59,159:160,<PUNCTUATION> = '==']
[60,161:161,<WS> = ' ']
[61,162:164,<STRING> = '"1"']
[62,165:165,<RPAREN> = ')']
[63,166:166,<RPAREN> = ')']
[64,167:167,<WS> = ' ']
[65,168:168,<SEMI> = ';']
[66,169:168,<EOF> = '<EOF>']
```

Parse Tree:

```
(query 
(query_expression (query_primary (select_query SELECT opt_distinct opt_top 
(select_item_list (select_item_list (select_item_list (select_item 
(expression (expression_body (identifier_up_to_two_parts col1))) opt_alias)) , 
(select_item (expression (expression_body (identifier_up_to_two_parts col2))) opt_alias)) , 
(select_item (expression (expression_body (identifier_up_to_two_parts col3))) opt_alias)) 
(opt_select_query_clause_list (select_query_clause_list (select_query_clause_list (select_query_clause (select_from_clause 
(table_from_clause FROM (table_from_source (join_expression (aliased_table (input_rowset (identifier_up_to_two_parts T1)) opt_alias))))))) (select_query_clause 
(where_clause WHERE (expression (expression_body ( (expression (expression_body 
(func_call NS1 . Func1 ( (expression (expression_body (identifier_up_to_two_parts col1))) , (expression (expression_body 123)) ))) 
(expression_tail (common_clause_token ==) 
(expression (expression_body (identifier_up_to_two_parts false))))) )) 
(expression_tail (common_clause_token AND) 
(expression (expression_body ( 
(expression (expression_body (func_call String . IsNullOrEmpty ( 
(expression (expression_body (func_call Func2 ( 
(expression (expression_body (identifier_up_to_two_parts col2))) )))) )))) )))))
) // JS: End of "where" tree
)))))) 
AND ( NOT ( NS2 . Func3 ( col3 ) == "1" ) ) ;)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like `AND` isn't the problem - the first `AND` got parsed properly in fact: `(expression_tail (common_clause_token AND)`.

However, I see no definition that would accept `NOT (<expression>)`.

Comment: Jiri ! thank you so much for taking the time to look into this. I fixed it as per your suggestion.
Happy New Year!